# Multi users application

Tags: java, percona

I'm developing a very critical application for hospital, I have one problem appeared 3 days ago, if two users showing patients table for amounts they owes to hospital, if one user change the amount the value will not updated on the other user side.

Example:
Patient: John Fremlin, Amount : $ 130
Two users showing the List
User1: updated the value to : $ 140
User2: Still see : $ 130

How can I automatically update the user2 list?

I'm using:

- Percona server (MySQL) 5.6.14
- Java SE 1.7.45
- Ubuntu Server

Comment: Check if the value was updated to DB or not!

Comment: It is impossible to provide an answer without looking into the code. Please share the **relevant** snippets.

Comment: Checking value each time, mean extra load on the server, it not good practice to do that, if user1 post the value 130 this will be a disaster since it should be 140. is there a library for java help in this staff.

Comment: This question will likely be closed if you don't provide the relevant piece of code.

Comment: The client application is a web application?

Comment: Desktop Application connecting to a central database server

Comment: Why closing the question? I'm asking for help. i need one way to update user2 table with new value when it updated on database.

Comment: What exactly does `update` mean? Do you want to push information to `user2`? Your question is still too broad. In case you cannot provide code, describe your use case (step by step!).

Comment: Patient: Johan Amount : 130, User1 & User2: Monitoring the same Patient User1: Changed the Amount to: 140 i need a way to show 140 for User2.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to have a **event-driven and non-blocking I/O programming model** that makes your application efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications and also will able to run across distributed devices. Below is few links you can refer --

1. [Vertx framework for java application](http://vertx.io/)
2. [Axon Framework for java application](http://www.axonframework.org/)

If you are familiar with **Spring framework** then you can take help of the event driven-driven programming of it, and also other required library that may resolve you problem that may come after your current issue.

There is **JavaFX framework** (Latest replacement of Swing) has a lot more support for event triggerings, bindings, Listeners.. You can take avail of it.

If you take advantage of MVC design pattern and architect your application in 3-tier in order to tackle with all your problems.

Hope this can help you out.
Thanks!

Comment: Since i have my ready application, i need to make it work without the need to change a lot of cods. If i need to use Spring i don't know how to start. Ex.: My Application Is ready now, how to convert it to work using Spring or JavaFX?

Answer (score 0):

After searching, i found what i need, a 3-tier application will fix these issues.